# Debug apps to Windows 10 X Emulator Error

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

When I want to debug the apps to Windows 10x Emulator 10.0.19563.0 (Preview).

Anyone facing the same issue?

Herewith the Error:

[image]

The latest emulator screenshot
[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, do you've found any solution yet?

Comment: @Cristian126 I solved it with the update of Insider version 19569.1000

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that your emulator is not assigned an IP, which will cause Visual Studio to fail to connect to the emulator

Please follow the steps below, it may solve your problem:

1. Launch `Microsoft Emulator Manager` as administrator
2. Disable GPU in the emulator's settings (`Edit`)
3. Try to deploy the app via Visual Studio after launching the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this happens when the emulator failed to start up.  When you encountered this error, was the emulator running and if so, was it fully booted to the desktop?

Comment: The Emulator is running and fully booted to the desktop

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  Based on your screenshot of the emulator manager, it looks like we are failing to resolve an IP for the emulator.  Can you confirm for us if you see an IP in the emulator OS under Settings -> Network & Internet -> View hardware and connection properties -> IPv4 Address?

And to unblock you, can you try disabling HyperV under Windows optional features, restarting, and then re-enabling it.  We have seen that resolve network related HyperV issues in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the update of Windows Insider version 19569.1000 and remember enable developer mode